# Laravel with https can't open on production (site can't be reached)

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, https, ssl-certificate

I am deploy Laravel on ubuntu 18.04 apache to production with SSL certificate.
When i open the web on server's browser with https (i.e https ://example.co), the web open perfectly with valid certificate.

But when i open on other PC (with different network) using https://example.co, i got this error

```
This site can’t be reached
Check DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

but if i use http://www.example.co on other PC  (with different network), the web is ok and can working.

here is my conf in /etc/apache2/site-enabled/laravel.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 10.xx.x.xxx
    ServerAlias www.example.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
    SSLEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/private/domain.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/ssl/certs/intermediate.crt"

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;  includeSubDomains"
    <Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 10.x.xx.xxx
   DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
   <Directory /var/www/laravel>
          AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

here is my .htaccess on /laravel/public/.htaccess

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

.env

```
 APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=https://example.co
```

is there configuration that i've missing?

Comment: Have set your DNS?

Comment: `Check DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` means that there are no DNS information available for the hostname you provided. Check your DNS settings for the domain.

Comment: yes, already done, coz it working when using http:// example.co when i open on public network. the problem when using https